# How to merge rows in a CSV with identical column values with Powershell or Batch?

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV file as such:

`ID,PRODUCT,QUANTITY
1,Beer,5
2,Coke,10
1,Beer,20
2,Coke,30`

I would like to consolidate the CSV file based on the values of the `PRODUCT` column. How can this be done in either Batch or PowerShell?

To clarify, the target CSV file is:

`ID,PRODUCT,QUANTITY
1,Beer,25
2,Coke,40`

---

Update #1

Using the answer to the question @Ashish linked - I've come up with this but I have a feeling I'm getting the wrong end of the stick. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
Import-Csv Data.csv | Group-Object Name |
Select @{n="ID";E={($_.name -split ',')[0]}},
Select @{n="PRODUCT";E={($_.name -split ',')[0]}},
Select @{n="Value";e={($_.group | measure-object value -sum).sum}} |
Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Read the answer to that other question again. Do you see multiple `Select` keywords?

Comment: Oh dear... Very dopey. Came up with a solution from the original question.